# Use number in where condition in Laravel Query

Tags: php, laravel

The below query works well in mysql but how to represent the same thing using Laravel.

```
select * from user_subscription where vendor_id = 'user_100' 
and 0 = (select count(*) from user_restricted_dates where vendor_id = 'user_100')
```

I tried with code but gives error as **unknown column '0' in where clause**

```
$list = UserSubscription::where('vendor_id', '=', $vendor_obj->vendor_id)
    ->where(0, '=', "(select count(*) from user_restricted_dates where vendor_id = 'user_100'")
    ->get();
```

Well the error indicates what it is but how to represent it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `where` method of the Query Builder maps the first value you pass to a field in the model. You'd have to use the `whereRaw` method instead.

```
$list = UserSubscription::where('vendor_id', '=', $vendor_obj->vendor_id)
    ->whereRaw("0 = (select count(*) from user_restricted_dates where vendor_id = 'user_100')")
    ->get();
```